# When reopening an application, how do I restore the zoomed state without causing problems?

Tags: macos

If the user zooms our app's main window, closes the app, then reopens it, we want to restore the last state of the main window, so we zoom it before showing the window. The app opens zoomed, so everything is great.

However, if the user clicks the zoom button again, nothing happens. I believe this is because the [documentation for zoom:](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSWindow_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSWindow/zoom%3a) says for step 5:

> Determines a new frame. If the window is currently in the standard
>   state, the new frame represents the user state, saved during a
>   previous zoom. If the window is currently in the user state, the new
>   frame represents the standard state, computed in step 1 above. If
>   there is no saved user state because there has been no previous zoom,
>   the size and location of the window do not change.

I think it doesn't unzoom because there's no user state, but I'm not sure why - shouldn't the user state be "the size the windows was at before it was zoomed"? If not, how can I make sure the user state is set properly so that the window un-zooms when the user clicks the zoom button again?

Edit: MrGomez responds below that this is basically how it's meant to work. This doesn't seem to be how other apps behave, though. Try Safari - Zoom it, then quit, then reopen the window, and it restores at the zoomed size. Click the zoom button and it goes back to a smaller size. iCal is the same. How are those apps doing it?

Answer (score 2):

The trouble is, this is the expected behavior. As you mentioned here:

> we want to restore the last state of the main window, so we zoom it
>   before showing the window

You've gone ahead and set the user's view as your standard view. The original default view has not been preserved.

[This thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3466832/how-to-reverse-a-nswindow-zoom-method-call) goes into detail about the expected functionality of `zoom:`. Quoting the accepted answer:

> According to the documentation for the `zoom:` method (note the `:`), the
>   inverse of `zoom:` is `zoom:`:
>
> *This action method toggles the size and location of the window between
>   its standard state (provided by the application as the “best” size to
>   display the window’s data) and its user state (a new size and location
>   the user may have set by moving or resizing the window).*
>
> If it's in the user state (not zoomed), it'll change to the standard
>   state (zoom), and if it's in the standard state (zoomed), it'll change
>   to the user state (unzoom).
>
> The documentation also notes:
>
> *If there is no saved user state because there has been no previous
>   zoom, the size and location of the window do not change.*
>
> This is what will happen if you started the window out in its standard
>   state; since it was never in any other state, there is nothing for it
>   to unzoom back to.

The trouble is you've overrided the standard state; `zoom:`'s purpose is to toggle between the user's view and your interface's standard view. To save a user's window state for later restore, follow [this guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/WinPanel/Tasks/SavingWindowPosition.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000229-BCIDIHBB).

And, for reference, here's the remainder of [OSX's style guidelines](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/userexperience/conceptual/applehiguidelines/Windows/Windows.html) and [a very good tutorial](http://macdevcenter.com/pub/a/mac/2002/05/16/cocoa.html) for how you should work with this restriction.

---

**Edit:** As discussed, this is also a question of UI modality and the fact OSX windows may be bimodal (user state, maximized state) or trimodal (user state, standard state, maximized state) with a loss of the user state when an application is closed in maximized state. This appears to reproduce itself with stock-standard applications for OSX, including, for example, [iCal.app](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ICal).

As a result, the best that can be done here is to define a functioning UI paradigm that's consistent with applications for OSX, but carries many of the same [idiosyncrasies of the little green glob](http://www.actsofvolition.com/archive/2004/january/themysterious).

Comment: This doesn't seem to be how other apps behave, though. Try Safari - Zoom it, then quit, then reopen the window, and it restores at the zoomed size. Click the zoom button and it goes back to a smaller size. iCal is the same. How are those apps doing it?

Comment: @Colen To the best of my knowledge, they're doing [this](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/WinPanel/Tasks/SavingWindowPosition.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000229-BCIDIHBB). I'll update my answer with this, because it's inappropriately terse without it.

Comment: OK, I created a small test application that does nothing but call setFrameUsingName / saveFrameUsingName at startup / shutdown to save and restore the window position. If I launch it, move it to somewhere else on the screen, close it, and relaunch it, the new position is restored. If I zoom it, close it, and relaunch it, the zoomed position is restored. All as expected so far. However, if I then hit zoom to unzoom it, it unzooms to the *default* window position - not the *new* window position I used. I'd be fine with that behavior - any idea how to trigger that? Thanks for your help so far!

Comment: @Colen That's because at the moment you triggered `zoom:`, you toggled from the user's view to the interface's standard view. Needless to say, for most UI developers in OSX, this is quite surprising behavior! Unfortunately, this will require you to set the standard interface view to the _new_ position specified by the user,   which may be equally surprising to those used to OSX's style guidelines and window behavior. Thus, I leave the design decision to you: do you set the standard view to the user's desired position, or do you leave it as is?

Comment: Sorry, when I say I zoomed the window, I mean I literally clicked the green "zoom" button in the application's UI. I didn't call "zoom:" at all in code - all I did was click the button in the UI. So other than saving and restoring the position in the OS-standard way, I'm not doing anything in code with the position / dimensions. Does that make sense?

Comment: From what I understand, [the little green "zoom" button triggers the same behavior as `zoom:`](http://www.actsofvolition.com/archive/2004/january/themysterious). Thus, you're actually running into the exact same issue. :)

Comment: If that's what the default behavior is, that's fine. I just don't understand how to trigger this in my app. :( When you reload your app and it comes back "zoomed", and you click the zoom button again, how does Mac OS decide what size to put it back at? I'm happy to pick an appropriate size, I just don't understand how to do it... apparently the test application I made just does it automatically, but my real app (which is much more complex) does not. :(

Comment: @Colen It's all relative to the [user's default setting](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/WinPanel/Tasks/SavingWindowPosition.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000229-BCIDIHBB). When an application comes back, OSX will interrogate the user's defaults and reconstruct the user view from last time. If this fails, it'll fall back to the standard view. That is, to my knowledge, how this system works. I'm sorry it's confusing, but then, I'm not the one that designed it. :)

Comment: @Colen For the remainder of this discussion, I'm going to move over to chat. I can be found there if you have any further questions!

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/9432/discussion-between-mrgomez-and-colen)

Comment: But that's the thing, there is no default being saved. You can use [NSWindow stringWithSavedFrame] to see the string that gets saved in the user defaults - all it has is two window rects, the current one and (what looks like) the maximum window size. There's no "default size" being saved like I assumed there was...